# Conditional formatting excel Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data on "Trainers" sheet.

I have a calendar of events on "schedule"

I want to add some conditional formatting on each cell to lookup itself in the "Trainers" sheet and check if selected trainer is able to perform the training (this will be determined by the applicable result column in the VLOOKUP)

At the moment I have in Cell O12 in "Schedule" but it's not getting any luck. I want the conditional formatting to trigger if the result of the VLOOKUP is anything except 0.

current formula in conditional formula for O12

```
="VLOOKUP(O12,Trainers!$A$1:$V$50,20,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Try `=ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(O12,Trainers!$A$1:$V$50,20,FALSE))`. Add more detail to your post to get a more efficient solution.

Comment: Only `Match()` or `COUNTIFS()` may work. Post few of your sample data.

Comment: Add a hidden column that calculates what you want per row. Then your formulas are much more easy to debug *and* your conditional formatting formulas are much simpler.

Comment: Using `MATCH()` or `XMATCH()` is suffice. Because both returns the position of the required value, if not found it returns `#N/A` error, when used in `Conditional Formatting` it will highlight for the one which is found and for the errors it will not highlight. Also please provide some sample data, so we can reproduce what you are trying to accomplish. I believe its very simple with the said functions i have mentioned.